# how to debug a shared library loaded in python

Tags: c++, debugging, python-3.x, dll, ctypes

I'd like to debug a shared lib (.dll on windows) called by python3.5-script. 
The dll compiled using minGW and is compiled with debug-info. In python it is loaded using ctypes.

When using gdb, it could not find the debugging symbols of python.

```
../../gdb-7.6.1/gdb/minsyms.c:862: internal-error: sect_index_data not initialized 
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

c code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl function1(int type)
{
    cout << "function 1 called" << endl;
}
```

python:

```
import ctypes
dlltest = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("../../Debug/libtest.dll")
dlltest.function1(0)
```

How could I debug the shared lib?

Comment: Python 3.5 is built with VC++ from Visual Studio 2015. The installer allows you to install debug versions of the EXEs and DLLs/PYDs and the associated PDBs with debug info. To actually use any of this you'll need to build your extension with Visual Studio 2015 (the community edition is free for non-commercial use). Then use its debugger or one of the [Windows platform debuggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551063) such as WinDbg or cdb.

Comment: BTW, `cdll.LoadLibrary` just calls `CDLL`, but without letting you pass parameters such as `handle`, `use_errno`, and `use_last_error`. So it's more typing and less useful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Is it possible to build python with MinGW?
The shared lib is build in MinGW / MinGW-W64, and could not attach debug information in the format used by WinDBG. (COFF seems to be not recognised by WinDBG.

Comment: I've never tried to build Python with MinGW on Windows. I recall there are patches to enable building with MinGW, but I think getting that to work will be much more difficult than simply compiling your extension in MSVC to use the official debug binaries and PDB files.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer.